# Convert Leads to Contacts

Tags: apex, leads, list, lead-conversion

I have the following code:

```
public List<Lead> leadsToConvert;
public void convertLead(){

    leadsToConvert = [Select id, FirstName, Lastname, Company FROM Lead];

    try
    {
        Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();
        for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
            accNames.add(l.Company);
        }

        //Create your map using Name as the key
        Map<String,Account> accMap = new Map<String,Account>();
        for(Account a : [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name = :accNames]){
            accMap.put(a.Name,a);
        }

        //Assemble List<Database.LeadConvert>
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
            Database.LeadConvert lcc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lcc.setLeadId(l.Id);
            //if there is an existing account with the same name
            //convert the lead into that account by grabbing the
            //id from the map above
            if(accMap.containsKey(l.Company)){
                lcc.setAccountId(accMap.get(l.Company).Id);
                lcc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
            }
            //set other values
            leadConverts.add(lcc);
        }
        //do other processing
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Catch error
    }

}
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You never actually convert the collection...you need to call the method from Database

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it not performing as expected? Please don't make us guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add Database.convertLead(lcc); after your for loop like below.

//Assemble List<Database.LeadConvert>
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
            Database.LeadConvert lcc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lcc.setLeadId(l.Id);
            //if there is an existing account with the same name
            //convert the lead into that account by grabbing the
            //id from the map above
            if(accMap.containsKey(l.Company)){
                lcc.setAccountId(accMap.get(l.Company).Id);
                lcc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
            }
            //set other values
            leadConverts.add(lcc);
        }
        ***Database.convertLead(lcc);***
        //do other processing
```

Comment: No no, I need not to create a new opportunity.

Comment: What I need to know is why the method is not working. It does nothing

Comment: I see - sorry about that.  You're only building a list of leads to convert, you need to envoke the convert method at the end.

Database.convertLead(lcc); - Where the //do other processing is.

Comment: Like this:  //set other values
                leadConverts.add(lcc);
                Database.convertLead(lcc);

Comment: No, you want to do it OUTSIDE of your for loop or you'll convert the list every time you iterate and blow out your limits.

Comment: edited my initial reply.